# Make array from lines between two tokens

Tags: php, regex

what is wrong with this code:
I need to make one array from lines between the tokens: START is starting and END is ending token; 
I have this type of text file:

```
 123-456-6541 (P) 
 you got page one
 second line
 third line
 END
 123-456-6541 (P) 
 you got page one
 second line
 another line 
 END
```

this is php code; it supposed to keep inserting lines into array untill it reaches second token:

```
        <?php
        $fh = fopen('text2.txt','r');
        while ($line = fgets($fh)) {    $lines[] = $line; }

        $active = false;
        $temp = "";
        $result = array();

            for ($i = 0; $i < count ($lines); $i++ )
            {
                     $line = $lines[$i];

                       if  ( strpos ( $line , ' 123-456-6541 (P)' ) !== false )
                                 {  
                                            $result[]= $line;
                                            $active = true;
                                 }      
                            if (strpos($line, 'END') !== false ) {
                                                      $active = false;
                                } 

            if ($active)
                $result[] = $line; 
            }   

                    print_r ( $result );
```

Following is desired result:

```
        Array
(
[0] => you got page one
       second line
       third line

[1] => you got page one 
       second line
       another line
 )
```

Comment: that's because your current condition check is supposed to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit: rewriting since source data example changed

```
$t = <<< EOF
 123-456-6541 (P)
 you got page one
 second line
 third line
 END
 123-456-6541 (P)
 you got page one
 second line
 aanother line
 END

EOF;

preg_match_all( "/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[ ]+\(P\)(.*)END/msU", $t, $r );

print_r( $r );
```

This will match the phone number pattern and spit out the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123-456-6541 (P)
 you got page one
 second line
 third line
 END
            [1] => 123-456-6541 (P)
 you got page one
 second line
 aanother line
 END
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
 you got page one
 second line
 third line

            [1] => 
 you got page one
 second line
 aanother line

        )

)
```

Comment: I can't user regular expression because in one token line I have pair of ()

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The () would be matched just fine as long as tokens are unique?

Comment: Yes I was not able to match this line with regex:
 
 `123-599-3556 (P)`

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide a complete example of material being parsed, without the "__ line" lorem-ipsum?

Comment: Are these phone numbers always exact, or are they phone-number patterns? Is the end always "END?"  If the phone numbers are always exact, you can escape ( with a \(.

Comment: yes tokens ( phone number ) is always the same, starting and ending. Anyway above solution gives error: `syntax error, unexpected $end`

Comment: Sorry, seems comment filtered out my \ (. Editing the post to match.

Comment: Just 2notes: I tried use regex but it seemed to that it gives error on closing parenthesis P) even though i escaped it. 
b) what is [ ] in regex -- a space ? thanks for help..

Comment: I don't believe you're being entirely forthcoming with your source data or you changed the query from what's above. There should not be any errors in the match I wrote - just no matches if the data is different. And yes, that's a space.

Comment: No, :) i meant I tried my regex before i used SO ( your code is working ok - that's why i voted it as correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

`strpos ( $line , 'TOK1' ) !== false` and `strpos ( $line , 'TOK' ) !== false` will both be true for `TOK1`. You are setting active to false right after you set it to true. (this information is no longer valid because the question was edited)

With this new information, you should be able to craft a solution ...

**EDIT**

If I were going to do it, it would look something like this. Granted, this does not take a lot of things into account, but it's a start, and I don't know what your ultimate goal is:

I edited the code again to match your new file layout ...

```
$lines = file('text2.txt');

$result = array();
$i      = 0;
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(strpos($line, 'END') !== false){
        $i++;
    } else {
        $result[$i][] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: I had to re-evaluate the process and it seemed that not using array ( file ) and put all file into string ( file_get_contents ) is better in this case.